# could not find implicit value for FromRecord

Tags: scala, avro4s

I'm trying to get started with avro & avro4s and I'm running into trouble getting a silly example working.

I can't even get my own version of a test found in the source repo to compile - https://github.com/sksamuel/avro4s/blob/master/avro4s-core/src/test/scala/com/sksamuel/avro4s/AvroJsonInputTest.scala#L14-L20

I'm getting the error mentioned in the title `could not find implicit value for parameter fromRecord: com.sksamuel.avro4s.FromRecord[Foo]`.

```
package test

import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream

import com.sksamuel.avro4s._
import org.specs2.mutable.Specification

class AvroSpec extends Specification {
  "My classes" should {
    "be deserialized by avro" in {
      case class Foo(num: Int, name: String)
      val json = """{ "num": 17, "name": "jibba-jabbba" }"""
      val inst = Foo(num = 17, name = "jibba-jabba")
      val in =  new ByteArrayInputStream(json.getBytes("UTF-8"), 0, json.length)
      val foo = new AvroJsonInputStream[Foo](in).iterator.toSet
      in.close()

      foo mustEqual Set(inst)
    }
  }
}
```

I'm using Scala 2.11.8 and avro 1.7.0.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I am able to serialize my actual domain objects using avro4s, it's just the deserialization that's a problem.

Answer (score 2):

Move the case class declaration outside the method definition:

```
package test

import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream

import com.sksamuel.avro4s._
import org.specs2.mutable.Specification

case class Foo(num: Int, name: String)
class AvroSpec extends Specification {
  "My classes" should {
    "be deserialized by avro" in {
      val json = """{ "num": 17, "name": "jibba-jabbba" }"""
      val inst = Foo(num = 17, name = "jibba-jabba")
      val in =  new ByteArrayInputStream(json.getBytes("UTF-8"), 0, json.length)
      val foo = new AvroJsonInputStream[Foo](in).iterator.toSet
      in.close()

      foo mustEqual Set(inst)
    }
  }
}
```